# Loop is not repeating

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to make this "algorithm", which will take the number and get  it down to 4, 2, 1. If anyone have seen the youtube video regarding this math problem, they will understand.

```
done = False

while True:
    num = int(input("Enter a number: "))  
    if (num % 2) == 0:  
        print(num/2)  
    else: 
        print(num * 3 + 1)
    if num == 1 or 2 or 4:
        break
```

The output is this algorithm not repeating itself.
If I type in number 5 it will x3+1, and print only 16. What I want is it doing this, but keep going till the number is either 1,2 or 4. Hope yall can help :D

Comment: ```if num == 1 or 2 or 4``` won't test num for 1, 2 and 4, only for 1. 2 and 4 are processed as boolean => True, and you break. You should explicitly compare 3 times (for example)

Comment: `if num == 1 or 2 or 4` --> `if num in [1,2,4]`

Comment: @balderman, I also just learned that a tuple -- so `if num in (1,2,4)` -- is even better than using a list. The items are of the same type, the size of the thing is fixed, and an immutable thing suffices in this case.

Comment: Your other problem is that you're not re-assigning another value to `num`. I think that after testing `num` to be even, you need to re-assign half of that to `num` again: `num = (num/2)`, and move the first assignment to outside of the `while` loop.

Answer (score 2):

The error is in line `if num == 1 or 2 or 4:`. That always evaluates to `True` and thus breaks your loop.

Your intention is to have `if num == 1 or num == 2 or num == 4:`. Or `if num in (1,2,4):` to be more concise.

(Explanation of your mistake: the `if` statement has an expression that is being tested. You're chaining a couple of expressions with the `or` operator, resulting in `if expr1 or expr2 or expr3`. The if-expression is `True` if any of those OR'd expressions is `True`.

Your `expr1` is `num == 1` which is `True` only if `num` equals `1`.

Your `expr2` is `2` which is `True` always (!).

Your `expr3` is `4` which is `True` always.

So, your if-expression is always evaluating to `True`.)

Comment: A tuple (```if num in (1, 2, 4)```) would be preferable. The performance difference is insignificant here but it's generally a better choice. Or even better, a set (```if num in {1, 2, 4}```).

Comment: Yes, that's a good one. I'll edit that. The list contains items of the same type, and is immutable, so a tuple is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't testing for all three of those numbers (1, 2 and 4).

Here's the fixed code:

```
done = False

while True:
    num = int(input("Enter a number: "))  
    if (num % 2) == 0:  
        print(num/2)  
    else: 
        print(num * 3 + 1)
    if num == 1:
        break
    if num == 2:
        break
    if num == 4:
        break
```

Comment: it still only gives me 1 output. Isnt there a way of making it do this a bunch of times, until it reaches 4,2 or 1

Comment: If it's still not working for you, I don't really know how to help. Sorry.

Comment: can you add my discord? Æble#8979
Maybe you could send me the output you get or something :D

Comment: This is the output I'm getting:

Comment: ~$ python3 loop.py
Enter a number: 3
10
Enter a number: 4
2.0

Comment: 1) Move the first assignment to `num` to outside of the `while` loop. 2) Re-assign `num` to a new number inside the `while` loop: `num = num / 2` if `num` is even.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to repeat num/2 or num*3+1 every output. If you use odd number like 7, it calculates 22 and 22 is a even number and 22 is calculated 11 and it returns 34 and so on. I figure it out like this. But it always ends with 4 :)

```
done = False
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
while True:
    if (num % 2) == 0:  
        num/=2
        print(num)
    else:
        num = num * 3 + 1
        print(num)
    if int(num) in [1,2,4]:
        break
```